# bash script to cd into directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, cd-command

This bash file running on Mac terminal failed to change the directory. Rather reporting it does not exist when it actually does. Any thing I did wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
read name
APPLICATION_PATH="~/Documents/meteor/apps/$name"
cd "${APPLICATION_PATH}"
```

Comment: Try replacing `~` with `$HOME`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two points:

- Problems with tilde expansion
- Problems with sourcing vs. executing.

For the tilde part, a very recent question at superuser was about the same issue (https://superuser.com/questions/1161493/why-bash-script-wont-extend-bashrc/1161496#1161496)

The tilde is expanded before the variable, so the cd cannot find the path. To overcome this, lead the command with `eval` as such:

```
eval cd "${APPLICATION_PATH}"
```

Unfortunately, when you execute the script (I mean, if it is chmod'ed to "+x", calling the path), you will see that the $PWD does not change in the "current shell". However if you add such a line at the end of the script

```
ls
```

You will see that, `ls` is executed at the new working directory. How come?

The answer is here (https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip#176788)

> Short answer: sourcing will run the commands in the current shell
>   process. executing will run the commands in a new shell process. still
>   confused? then please continue reading the long answer.

Shortly, to change the $PWD at current shell, you should "source" the script as such:

```
source /path/to/script
```

or

```
. /path/to/script
```

A third point: If you don't want to mess with `source` or `.`, you can define an alias in your ~/.bashrc (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752525/run-bash-script-as-source-without-source-command):

> alias mycmd="source mycmd.sh"

Comment: I tend to _always_ use `$HOME` rather than `~` in scripts. Looks better too, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

you can use tilda '~' you just need to have turned on the proper bash expansion key

```
set -x
```

or use either full path '/Volumes/Swap/Apps/...'

use bashrc to set env shortcuts like

```
export LocalApps=/Users/me/Applications
export SysApps=/Applications
```

i wouldn't use eval

if you just want to suck in a string from the command line you don't need to use read just grab the arg

```
if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
    #check if it's directory
    if [[ -d $name ]] ; then
      #do stuff here
    else
      echo 'bomb'
    fi
else
  usage
fi
```

instead of 'cd-ing' to a directory learn how to use ~+, ~-, pushd and popd, 
many times you don't need to actually 'cd' into a directory

you might do something this

```
pushd $SysApps/$name
  do stuff 
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put ~ inside ""

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
read name
APPLICATION_PATH=~/Documents/meteor/apps/$name
cd "${APPLICATION_PATH}"
pwd
```

Answer (score 0):

A alternative work around even though it won't exactly cd into the directory from the script in the current terminal window you are using, it will open a another terminal and cd into the directory you want, using osascript:

```
osascript -e "
    tell application \"Terminal\"
        do script \"cd $APPLICATION_PATH; pwd;\"
        set bounds of front window to {900, 0, 1790, 565}
    end tell"
```

it worked for me when I was writing a script to create new virtual hosts. "set bounds of front window" is optional.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).